# SQL query for max value in between two timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table which has column pressure, temperature, real time.
i want to write a query which will select the maximum value of pressure between two time inputs, present in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below:

For that realtime datatype must datetime.

```
SELECT max(pressure) FROM pressure WHERE realtime BETWEEN (starttime) AND (endtime);
```

Please have a look it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like :

```
select max(pressure)as pressure 
from table 
where realtime >= 'startTime' and realtime =<'endTime'
```